# How to create View Stub?

Tags: android, slider, viewstub

I am new to android.. I have a slider in my xml. For the particular value of the slider I want an Image to appear and later disappear.. I heard that View Stub can do the trick.. But not exactly getting the solution.. Can any one please help me..

Thanks,
Keerthiraj

Answer (score 1):

`ViewStub` is used when you have a "heavy" view which is hidden but may be shown later. `ViewStub` is a light-weight view which inflates the real view at run-time when it's made visible.

So `ViewStub` doesn't solve your problem. I thinks the best solution for you is to set `ImageView`'s visibility:

```
imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```